# Laravel flash message after login does not displayed in home route

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

First of all, I checked out this question: [Flash message after login laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42119645/flash-message-after-login-laravel), but it does not solve my issue.

I am trying to generate session flash message after successful login, by overriding `authenticated` method of `AuthenticatesUsers` Trait like the following:

```
// in LoginController
...
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
    {
        $request->session()->flash('status','success');
        $request->session()->flash('msg',__('Welcome back :name',['name' => $user->name]));
        return redirect('/');
    }
```

The flash message does not be displayed. However, when I set `return redirect('/anyOtherRoute')` it redirected to that route and the flash message is rendered successfully!

I, also, have tried to override `sendLoginResponse` method instead of  `authenticated` method like the following:

```
protected function sendLoginResponse(Request $request)
    {
        $request->session()->regenerate();

        $this->clearLoginAttempts($request);
        $request->session()->flash('status','success');
        $request->session()->flash('msg',__('Welcome back :name',['name' => '$user->name']));

        return $this->authenticated($request, $this->guard()->user())
                ?: redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
    }
```

Also there is no flash message there! Finally, I tried the checked answer for the regarded question: [Flash message after login laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42119645/flash-message-after-login-laravel), but it also does not make any difference:

```
use AuthenticatesUsers {
        redirectPath as laravelRedirectPath;
    }

public function redirectPath()
{
    // Do your logic to flash data to session...
    session()->flash('status','success');
    session()->flash('msg',__('Welcome back :name',['name' => '$user->name']));
    // Return the results of the method we are overriding that we aliased.
    return $this->laravelRedirectPath();
}
```

The following is all of my LoginController code with commented any tries:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesUsers;
    /*use AuthenticatesUsers {
        redirectPath as laravelRedirectPath;
    }*/

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/';
    //protected $loginPath = 'admin';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'logout']);
    }
    protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
    {
        $request->session()->flash('status','success');
        $request->session()->flash('msg',__('Welcome back :name',['name' => $user->name]));
        return redirect('/job');
    }

    /*protected function sendLoginResponse(Request $request)
    {
        $request->session()->regenerate();

        $this->clearLoginAttempts($request);
        $request->session()->flash('status','success');
        $request->session()->flash('msg',__('Welcome back :name',['name' => '$user->name']));

        return $this->authenticated($request, $this->guard()->user())
                ?: redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
    }*/
    protected function sendFailedLoginResponse(Request $request)
    {
        $errors = [$this->username() => trans('auth.failed')];

        if ($request->expectsJson()) {
            return response()->json($errors, 422);
        }
        $request->session()->flash('status','danger');
        $request->session()->flash('msg',__('Error: Login failed. Incorrect username or password'));
        return redirect()->back()
            ->withInput($request->only($this->username(), 'remember'))
            ->withErrors($errors);
    }

    public function username()
    {
        return 'username';
    } 
   /* public function redirectPath()
{
    // Do your logic to flash data to session...
    session()->flash('status','success');
    session()->flash('msg',__('Welcome back :name',['name' => '$user->name']));
    // Return the results of the method we are overriding that we aliased.
    return $this->laravelRedirectPath();
}   */
}
```

#### Additional Notice:

The route `/` is defined as a chained method in the `web.php` routes like the following:

```
Route::get('/', ['as' => 'home', function () {    

    return view('welcome');
}])->middleware('auth');
```

Comment: Do  you have a place in your view at route '/' to render the flash message?

Comment: @MarkSkayff Yes, sure, I have flash message element included in the main layout. Additionally, there are many other flash messages rendered in the view of the route `/`

Comment: If you check your network console, are there any other requests after being redirected to `/`? Perhaps there's another redirect happening, causing your flashed message to get lost.

Comment: @AkenRoberts very good notice, and I'm almost sure that it is the cause. However, I could not able to figure out or to track the redirects from the network console to know where the extra redirect occurred for `/` route!

Comment: Open the network manager and click on persist logs. If there is another request taking place you have to see it.

Answer (score 0):

add "web" middleware to persist session as

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth', 'web']], function() {
    Route::get('/', ['as' => 'home', function () {
        return view('welcome');
    }]);
});
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but it does not solve the issue.

Comment: please check all routes file and check that there are no blank lines at end of a file.

Answer (score 0):

**In laravel 7 in my case working Properly:**

The following is all of my `LoginController.php` code with commented any tries:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;

    /**
     * Send the response after the user was authenticated.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    protected function sendLoginResponse(Request $request)
    {
        $request->session()->regenerate();

        $this->clearLoginAttempts($request);

        if ($response = $this->authenticated($request, $this->guard()->user())) {
            return $response;
        }

        return $request->wantsJson()
                    ? new Response('', 204)
                    : redirect()->back();
    }

    // protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
    // {
    //     $request->session()->flash('flash', 'Welcome!');
    // }

protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
 {
    $request->session()->flash('flash','danger');
    return redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
 }

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }
}
```

and in blade file :

```
  @if (session('flash'))
      <div class="alert alert-success">
          <p class="msg"> {{ session('flash') }}</p>
      </div>
  @endif
```