# Not authenticated message Laravel 5.6 (PHP)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6

I am new in Laravel and using **5.6 version**. I want that if user goes to a specific page that is authenticated it should redirect to login page and show a flash message for example the user goes to create post page which is authenticated and user is not authenticated so the login form is showed but I want a flash message also show on login page can anyone tell me where to set that message???

> **Note:** I'm using the built in Laravel Login sytem nothing changed!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42122868

Answer (score 0):

Laravel default authentication supports events. 
When user failed to authenticate the `App\Listeners\LogFailedLogin` event is being dispatched. 
You can hook your handler to that event and set session flash message there.

Comment: there is not any listeners folder inside App

Comment: I am new can u tell in detail

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/events#defining-listeners
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authentication

Answer (score 0):

You can set the message as a normal html code in your login page and put the `@guest...@endguest`

**For Example :**

```
<div class="alert alert-danger">
    <h2 class="text-center">Your Message here !!</h2> <!-- This is only a way to show u , it doesn't have to be like this-->
</div>
```

Hopefully this will work for you

Comment: Add it only in the login.blade.php file, u probably added it to the layouts/app.blade.php !

Comment: bro I mean if he directly go to login the message will be shown I don't need that I only need that when he was on the authenticated edit post page and then he clicked logout so the login form will be shown and then the message displayed not all time